# how to access jenkins credential through external groovy script CURL statement

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a groovy script which i am calling from my jenkins pipeline .
from that script i am executing a curl statement where password is required.
I want to use jenkins credential directly inside groovy script , do not want to use direct password how to get the password from jenkins credential .
please help me on this

```
String fetchTag(String url) {
  def response
  response = sh(returnStdout: true, 
script: "curl --insecure -X GET $url  -u admin:admin= -H 'cache-control: no-cache'").trim()
  println('RESP: ' + response)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'abcd', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME')]) {
        response = sh(
                returnStdout: true,
                script: "curl -X GET ${url} -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD"
                ).trim()
        }
```

Here abcd is the credential which needs to  be setup in jenkin